# A sequence $\{ x_{n}\}$ converges to $x \in (X, d)~$ if and only if $~\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} d(x_{n}, x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, solution-verification

$\blacksquare~$**Problem:** A sequence $\{ x_{n}\}$ converges to $x \in X~$ if and only if $$\lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_{n}, x) = 0$$
Where $(X, d)$ is a **Metric Space.**

---

$\blacksquare~$**My approach:**

$\bullet~$**If case :** Let's consider $x_n \rightarrow x$. Where $\{x_n\}$ $\in $ $ X ~$ and $~x $ $ \in $ $ X $.

We know from the definition of convergence of a sequence $\{ x_n \}$ $ \in $ $ X $ to $x$ $\in $ $ X $, [where $( X , d ) $ is a metric space] gives us the following-

> *For any given $\epsilon_n > 0, $ $\exists $ $ N $ $ \in $ $ \mathbb{ N } $*  such that,
> \begin{align*}
>      d ( x_n , x ) < \epsilon_n   \quad  \forall~  n \geqslant N
>  \end{align*}
> Now we can pick our $\epsilon_n < \frac{1}{n} $. Therefore we get by the properties of a metric-
> \begin{align*}
>     0 \leqslant d ( x_n , x ) < \epsilon_n < \frac{1}{n} 
> \end{align*}
> When we take $n \rightarrow \infty$ on both sides, we obtain:
> \begin{align*}
>     0 \leqslant \lim_{n \to \infty } d( x_n , x ) \leqslant 0
> \end{align*}
> Therefore, by **sandwich theorem** we obtain that, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} d( x_n , x ) $ exists and equals 0.

$\bullet~$**Only if case:** Let's consider $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} d ( x_n , x ) = 0 $.

> Therefore, from the definition of limit, we have, for any given $ \epsilon > 0,$ $ \exists$ $ N $ $ \in  $ $ \mathbb{N} $, such that
> \begin{align*}
>      d( x_n , x ) < \epsilon \quad \forall~ n \geqslant N \quad [ \text{As } d( a , b ) \geqslant 0~ \text{ for any } a, b \in X ]
> \end{align*}
> Therefore, we have obtained the result that, $ x_n \rightarrow x $ from the definition we have applied before .

Hence, we have got our needed solution.

---

Please check the solution for glitches :)

Comment: Your solution  is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your proof is fine.

The key point here is that $\lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n,x) = 0$ is the same as $\forall \epsilon > 0 \; \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N \implies d(x_n,x) < \epsilon,$ which you seem to have captured.